# Separating the digits of a number in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I am trying to code a program to separate the digits of a number in scheme. I take as input a number of any length. The output will be `n` number of `1`s where n is the length of the number. Eg:- 123 will output 1 1 1.
However, my code outputs 1 only once.

Why does this happen? What is the error in my code?

```
(define (separate x)
    (cond ((= 0 x) 0 )
          ((> 0 x) (separate (/ x 10))))
    1)
```

Also, how do I add the actual digits of the number to a list? I am getting confused about lists in scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code outputs `1` because in the last line that's what you return:

```
1)
```

It completely ignores the value of the `cond` expression (in Scheme only the value of the last expression is returned), and besides you're not doing anything with the result of the recursive call.

If you want to return a *list* then your base case changes - you must return an initial list and in the recursive step add a new element to that list using `cons`: that's the standard template for building an output list.

Also, notice that asking if `(< x 10)` is a better base case, if `x` happens to be `0` (an edge case) we must return a single-element list, not `0`. Assuming a non-negative input, this should work:

```
(define (separate x)
  (cond ((< x 10) '(1)) ; base case: return a single-element list
        (else (cons 1   ; recursive step: add `1` to the output list
                    (separate (quotient x 10)))))) ; and advance recursion
```

The output is as expected:

```
(separate 123)
=> '(1 1 1)
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks. I cam almost grasp the solution, but somehow I cannot grasp the solution completely. What can I do to increase my ability in Scheme programming? I am getting stumped even at simple problems like these.
I am about to contribute to an open source project for which I need some proficiency in Scheme.
Any tips for improving myself in Scheme?

Comment: Take a look at [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html), one of the best programming books ever written. It'll teach you the core concepts to program in Scheme.

Comment: I learned Scheme through SICP. I have understood the syntax. And I did pick up useful programming tips through it. However, I want practice. How can I do it?

Comment: I tried to modify the program above to print the actual digits. I added the statement (remainder x 10) instead of just returning 1 in the else part.
However, on (/ x 10) returns a floating point number. How do I get only an integer?

Comment: Use `(quotient x 10)` instead of `(/ x 10)`

Comment: Okay! I tried to use truncate, but it returned a floating number again. Thanks :)